# Arbitrary intersection of open set is not open in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We know that arbitrary intersection of open sets may not be open. The most common example to show this is taking $\mathbb R$ with usual metric and taking $U_n=(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$. Then intersection of $U_n$ is $\{0\}$ which is not open. I am trying to find more examples but in other metric spaces. Do we have some examples of such open sets other then in $\mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: The example straightforwardly generalizes; take $U_n$ to be the open ball of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ around any non-isolated point.

Comment: this may not be a metric space, but in the finite complement topology, where open sets have finite complements, an arbitrary intersection of open sets could have an infinite complement and thus not be open

Comment: @J.W.Tanner the finite complement topology is indeed a topology so arbitrary union of open sets is always going to be open. I think there is some mistake in the comment.

Comment: Thanks, @Mathfun, I mistyped union where I meant intersection; I changed it

Comment: All points in a metric space $X$ are closed, so the sets $U_x = X \setminus \{x\}$ are open.  Intersections of these can recover every possible subset of $X$, open or not.

Comment: @RaviFernando: I think you should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All points in a metric space $X$ are closed, so the sets $U_x = X \setminus \{x\}$ are open.  Intersections of these can recover every possible subset of $X$, open or not.